# Problems creating a copy function for a linked list

Tags: c++

In this instance I am creating a queue implemented as a linked list. The queue has a pointer to the front and a pointer to the back.

Whenever I try to run the driver that tests the queue the program crashes shortly after starting an attempt at copying. My previous linked list program also had issues with the copy function, so I am unable to use it as a reliable reference.

The following code is my copy function:

```
template<class T>
void queue<T>::copy(const queue<T>& original){
  QNodeType<T>* current;
  QNodeType<T>* addin;
  addin = new QNodeType<T>;
  current = original.front_;
  count=original.count;

  if(front_ != NULL){
    destroy();
  }

  if(original.front_==NULL){
    front_=NULL;
    back_=NULL;
  }
  else{
    front_= new QNodeType<T>;
    addin->item=current->item;
    front_=addin;
    back_=addin;
    if(current->next != NULL){
      while(current->next != NULL){
        addin= new QNodeType<T>;
        addin->item=current->item;
        addin->next=NULL;
        back_->next=addin;
        back_=addin;
        current=current->next;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well first doing `front_= new QNodeType<T>;` then followed by `front_=addin;` is definitely not something that's going to work. It's like having `int a = 6; a = 7;` and wondering why `a` isn't equal to `6`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was going through my text book to see if I was missing out on any important steps in getting it to work properly, but I could not find any major differences.

Comment: When you single-step through the execution in a debugger for short list (zero, one, two elements), does it look right? Do the node pointers make sense at every step?

Comment: @Useless I am unfamiliar with how to use the debugger in codeblocks or any other program.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn then. No-one can easily help you with the behaviour of code you haven't posted. There's an explanation of what kind of code is useful here [in the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).